# Summing up node depths in a binary tree

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

To sum up all the nodes' depths in any given binary tree, I've written the following recursive algorithm:

```
def nodeDepths(root):
    final=0
    helper(root,0,final)
    return final

def helper(node,d,final):
    if not node:
        return 
    final+=d
    helper(node.left,d+1,final)
    helper(node.right,d+1,final)

class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

My thinking was: as I see each node, add the depth of that node to the final sum, then recursively call on the left and right so that they may do the same. At the end of the recursive call stack, the final sum should have the right value.

Actual result: the final sum is always 0.

Why does this not work?

Comment: Because the `helper` method is not returning anything substantial. You always return 0.

Comment: @pecey That's actually why I intended to make modifications to 'final'. I assumed the 'final' var that is passed into the helper each time modifies the 'final' as defined in nodeDepths(). Does the helper not modify the var 'final' by ref?

Comment: I think [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-python-call-by-reference-or-call-by-value/) would help you understand. But in short, when you pass the variable `final` to `helper`, it doesn't modify the `final` declared in `nodeDepths`. To do so, you will have to make `final` a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Python passes its arguments [by assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference). As a consequence, if a list was passed into the method above instead of a variable, it would work as in here:

```
def nodeDepths(root):
    final=[0]
    helper(root,0,final)
    return final[0]

def helper(node,d,final):
    if not node:
        return 
    final[0]+=d
    helper(node.left,d+1,final)
    helper(node.right,d+1,final)
```

In simple words,

- If a mutable object is passed in, it can be changed but if assigned to, the outside variable will not reflect the changes.
- If an immutable object is passed in, it cannot be changed and the outside variable will not reflect the change.